# mongodb find and remove a lot of data failes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, shell

Hei guys, this is my first Question in stackoverflow. I am working with mongodb and JavaScript. 
We inserted (a lot of) Data into mongo per JavaScript (if asked i am willing to attach).
And all suddenly the collection.update did not jump over already inserted values and so our db is with double values now. (now 140mio instead of ~120mio)

I've tried to delete those values with:

```
db.data.find({}, {ts_s_id:1}).sort({_id:1}).forEach(function(doc){
db.data.remove({_id:{$gt:doc._id}, ts_s_id:doc.ts_s_id});
});
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
2017-03-27T13:16:51.470+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: getMore command failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Cursor not found, cursor id: 18433357615",
"code" : 43,
"codeName" : "CursorNotFound"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor.prototype._runGetMoreCommand@src/mongo/shell/query.js:763:1
DBCommandCursor.prototype._hasNextUsingCommands@src/mongo/shell/query.js:791:9
DBCommandCursor.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:799:1
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:294:13
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:500:12
@(shell):1:1
```

and by this time I don't know how to optimize.

If anybody knows that error or was in this position before I would be really thankful for answeres.

Datasample is:

```
_id:58c075d4f0def621ba4be075
sensors_id:BME280_11_C
timestamp:2016-11-17 09:38:49.360
value:19.83

_id:58c075d4f0def621ba4be076
sensors_id:BME280_11_mbar
timestamp:2016-11-17 09:38:49.360
value:947.73

_id:58c075d4f0def621ba4be077
sensors_id:BME280_11_%
timestamp:2016-11-17 09:38:49.360
value:41.8984
```

Comment: It looks like you are running a nested query where the second tries to delete from the cursor while iterating. This is not a good solution. You can try to first query for the items you want to delete, using the aggregation framework, into a variable, and then delete all of them in another operation. Could you post the structure of your document?

Comment: Also the subject of your question does not match your description. Please update accordingly.